# button corner radius is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I give button corner redius using below code but it is not wokring

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
button.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

This code is not working.Please help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need to set button property clipsToBounds true

```
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line of code before the mentioned two statements.

```
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Nifty extension for `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {

   func setCornerRadius(amount: CGFloat, withBorderAmount borderWidthAmount: CGFloat, andColor borderColor: UIColor) {

        self.layer.cornerRadius = amount
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidthAmount
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
}
```

**Usage:**

`button.setCornerRadius(amount: 2.0, withBorderAmount: 2.0, andColor: .blue)`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line of code before the mentioned two statements.

```
buttonProfile.clipsToBounds = true
buttonProfile.layer.cornerRadius = buttonProfile.frame.size.width / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It always works for me

```
    func setCornerTo(_ button : UIButton , withRadius radius : CGFloat) 
    {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        button.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

and call like this . .

```
setCornerTo( myButton , withRadius: 5)
```